# exynos-mixer 14450000.mixer: [drm:exynos_drm_register_dma] *ERROR* Device 14450000.mixer lacks support for IOMMU

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine, arm, xen

We are trying to boot Xen on a Samsung XE303C12 Chromebook aka "snow" following the suggestions in the slide show presentation here:

https://www.slideshare.net/xen_com_mgr/xpds16-porting-xen-on-arm-to-a-new-soc-julien-grall-arm

This device uses an exynos5250 SOC dual core 1.7 GHz with 2 MB RAM, it is a Samsung armv7 chip with virtualization extensions.

In particular, we have it working fairly well both on the bare metal with a recent 6.1.59 Linux LTS kernel and also with a recent 5.4.257 LTS kernel with KVM, the older LTS kernel version is used to test KVM because support for KVM on arm v7 was removed from Linux around kernel version 5.7.

So we know we have the hypervisor mode enabled because we were able to use it with KVM.

For Xen, we are using the latest Debian build of Xen 4.17 for the Debian armhf architecture:

```
(XEN) Xen version 4.17.2-pre (Debian 4.17.1+2-gb773c48e36-1) 
(pkg-xen-devel@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) 
(arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0) debug=n Thu May 18 19:26:30 UTC 2023
```

The Linux kernel is a custom build that adds the Xen config kernel options (CONFIG_XEN_DOM0, etc) on top of a kernel that works well on the same Chromebook model on the bare metal.

Our method of booting is to have u-boot boot the Xen hypervisor and load the device tree after adding the dom0 to the otherwise unaltered device tree from the Linux kernel using u-boot fdt commands to add a /chosen node, as described on the Xen wiki and in the pages linked from there.

We have also tried adding and loading an initrd.img using the device tree /chosen node but that made no difference in our tests.We actually have the Linux LTS kernel version 6.1.59 working as dom0 with Xen using the same version of u-boot that we used for KVM, but with a big problem.

The problem we see is that when booting the 6.1.59 kernel version as dom0 with Xen, the screen is totally dark and the only way to access the system is remotely through ssh.

Logs indicate most everything else is working, such as the wifi card so we can access it remotely via ssh and a USB optical mouse lights up when connected so USB is also working.

Obviously, the disk is also working. The Chromebook is configured to boot from the device's SD card slot by turning on Chrome OS developer mode options to enable booting from the SD card slot.

The mystery is that when booting the exact same 6.1.59 kernel on the bare metal instead of booting it as dom0 on Xen, it boots up with full access to the screen and we can interact with the system using the X.org windows system. But booting as dom0 with Xen, the screen is totally dark and the only access we have to the system is through the network via ssh.

Also, when booting the 5.4.257 kernel with KVM in hypervisor mode, the screen works and we can interact with the system through the X.org windows system.

Exploring the log file,we have seen the errors below :With Xen (or in bare metal):

```
devuan-bunsen kernel: [drm] Exynos DRM: using 14400000.fimd device for DMA mapping operations

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: bound 14400000.fimd (ops 0xc0d96354)

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: bound 14450000.mixer (ops 0xc0d97554)

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: bound 145b0000.dp-controller (ops 0xc0d97278)

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: bound 14530000.hdmi (ops 0xc0d97bd0)

... 

devuan-bunsen kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: [drm] fb0: exynosdrmfb frame buffer device

devuan-bunsen kernel: [drm] Initialized exynos 1.1.0 20180330 for exynos-drm on minor 0
```

In this case,the kernel is able to use the exynos-drm kernel to start the fb0 device.

But with Xen we get this error with exynos-drm:

```
devuan-bunsen kernel: [drm] Exynos DRM: using 14400000.fimd device for DMA mapping operations

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: bound 14400000.fimd (ops 0xc0d96354)

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-mixer 14450000.mixer: [drm:exynos_drm_register_dma] *ERROR* Device 14450000.mixer lacks support for IOMMU

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: failed to bind 14450000.mixer (ops 0xc0d97554): -22

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-drm exynos-drm: adev bind failed: -22

devuan-bunsen kernel: exynos-dp: probe of 145b0000.dp-controller failed with error -22
```

We have started a post on the Xen ML but actually a workaround has not been found yet :

https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2023-10/msg00034.html

It seems that we shoud / could tweak the EXYNOS_IOMMU parameters in some way inside the kernel config file....or ?